# How to run UDP client and server (in C) on two remote hosts?

Tags: c, sockets, udp, client-server

I am new to socket programming. I wrote codes for UDP Client and Server which work fine on my computer. I want to run these programs on two different hosts, i.e. the Server on my computer and Client on my friend' computer. How do I do it without a router? Please mention if any specific changes are to be made in the code for the purpose.

Here's the code:

> **Receiver**

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#include<sys/socket.h>

#include<sys/types.h>

#include<netinet/in.h>

#include<netinet/ip.h>

#include<string.h>

#include<unistd.h>

int main() {
  int ret = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if (ret == -1) {
    printf("socket creation fails\n");
    exit(0);
  } else
    printf("socket creation succeeds\n");

  struct sockaddr_in sender;
  int port;
  printf("Enter port:");
  scanf("%d", & port);
  sender.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sender.sin_port = htons(port);
  sender.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;

  int ret1;
  ret1 = bind(ret, (struct sockaddr * ) & sender, sizeof(sender));

  if (ret1 == -1) {
    printf("socket binding fails\n");
    exit(0);
  }

  printf("socket binding succeeds\n");

  struct sockaddr_in receiver;
  char str[15], str2[15];
  int addrlen = sizeof(receiver);

  while (1) {
    int rec = recvfrom(ret, str, sizeof(str), 0, (struct sockaddr * ) & receiver, & addrlen);
    printf("Received:");
    str[rec] = '\0';
    if (strcmp(str, "exit") == 0)
      break;

    if (rec == -1) {
      printf("recvfrom fails\n");
      exit(0);
    }

    printf("%s\n", str);

    printf("Enter :");
    scanf("%s", str2);

    int recsend = sendto(ret, str2, strlen(str2), 0, (struct sockaddr * ) & receiver, sizeof(receiver));

    if (recsend == -1) {
      printf("sendto fails");
      exit(0);
    }

    if (strcmp(str2, "exit") == 0)
      break;
  }

  close(ret);
  return 0;
}
```

> **Sender**

```
#include<stdio.h>

#include<stdlib.h>

#include<sys/socket.h>

#include<sys/types.h>

#include<netinet/in.h>

#include<netinet/ip.h>

#include<string.h>

#include<unistd.h>

int main() {
  int ret = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
  if (ret == -1) {
    printf("\nsocket creation fails");
    exit(0);
  } else
    printf("\nsocket creation succeeds");

  struct sockaddr_in receiver;
  int port;
  printf("\nEnter port:");
  scanf("%d", & port);
  receiver.sin_family = AF_INET;
  receiver.sin_port = htons(port);
  receiver.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
  char str[15], str2[15];

  int addrlen1 = sizeof(receiver);
  struct sockaddr_in sender;
  int addrlen = sizeof(sender);
  while (1) {
    printf("Enter:");
    scanf("%s", str);

    int send = sendto(ret, str, strlen(str), 0, (struct sockaddr * ) & receiver, addrlen1);
    if (send == -1) {
      printf("sendto fails");
      exit(0);
    }

    if (strcmp(str, "exit") == 0)
      break;

    int senrec = recvfrom(ret, str2, sizeof(str2), 0, (struct sockaddr * ) & sender, & addrlen);
    printf("\n");
    printf("Received:");
    str2[senrec] = '\0';
    if (strcmp(str2, "exit") == 0)
      break;

    if (senrec == -1) {
      printf("recvfrom fails\n");
      exit(0);
    }

    printf("%s\n", str2);
  }
  close(ret);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Let your client know the ip address and the listening port of your server. They have to be connected to a network, what do you mean without router?

Comment: Somewhere on the internet it that said I need to do something called port forwarding using a router to achieve this.

Comment: And also, what kind of network do the computers have to be in? Please excuse me if the questions seem dumb, I am fairly new to network programming and I don't have the slightest clue how these things are done.

Comment: Any sort of internet connection will do it for you. Your client has to know the ip address of the server, and the port it listens to. You can quickly learn your ip address by googling "what is my ip". Just connect one of your computers to a mobile hotspot so they will be running on different networks.

Answer (score 0):

Connect both to different networks and get your server's ip address.

Change your client's `receiver` ip and port to:

```
receiver.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("8.8.8.8"); // Ip address of your server.
receiver.sin_port=htons(port); // Whatever port your server is listening to
```

Comment: I tried this but it's not working. Here's what I did - (1). Took my friend's computer and connected it to the internet. And connected my computer to my mobile hotspot. (2). Ran the server code in my computer with a port number, say 5000. Ran the client code on my friend's computer with the IP address of my computer and port number 5000.     But nothing really happened.

Comment: @jennyjenkins Is it the LAN IP address or your real IP address (obtained by Google searching "what is my ip")?

Comment: It is your global ip address @kiner_shah

Comment: @grizzly, Sorry, Global?

Comment: @kiner_shah I got the ip address by using the ifconfig command.

Comment: Isn't that IP address your LAN's IP address? Those are class 3 IP addresses. See [here](https://study-ccna.com/classes-of-ip-addresses/#:~:text=IP%20addresses%20from%20the%20first,of%20Internet%20IP%20addresses%20assignment.). Did you try the Google search method?